# How to skip a single jaxb element validation contained in a jaxb collection in Spring Batch Job?

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-batch

Client sends 50k customers in an xml file. I use [Spring Batch's JaxBMarshaller](http://org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller) and run in a Spring Batch job.

Spring batch job gets a file, processes, and writes.

Problem is, it's ALL or NONE validation with jaxb. If I have 50k objects and only 2 of them fail validation, I still need 49,998 objects to be processed by business.

There's a class, javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler; you can set it to JaxBMarshaller but it only returns true or false and provides no access to the object being marshaled.

I also added  on the chunk Reader; error still throws.

Sample schema:

```
<xs:element name="CustomerLists">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="Customer" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Customer"/>
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Sample Xml:

```
<a:CustomerLists xmlns:a="http://foo.com">

    <a:Customer>
        ...
    ...
        ...
    </a:Customer>

    <a:Customer>
        ...
    ...
    ...
    </a:Customer>

    <a:Customer>
        ...
    ...
    ...
    </a:Customer>

</a:CustomerLists>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler` is the correct mechanism to use with JAXB.  You can access the problematic object for an unmarshal operation through the `ValidationEvent`:

```
package blog.jaxb.validation;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

public class MyValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("\nEVENT");
        System.out.println("SEVERITY:  " + event.getSeverity());
        System.out.println("MESSAGE:  " + event.getMessage());
        System.out.println("LINKED EXCEPTION:  " + event.getLinkedException());
        System.out.println("LOCATOR");
        System.out.println("    OBJECT:  " + event.getLocator().getObject());
        return true;
    }


}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: event.getLocator().getObject() returns NULL

Comment: @pritam - On a marshal or unmarshal operation?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. How do we SKIP the invalid element to continue processing the rest of the XML? I am having the same problem. It doesn't look like JAXB allows us to do this.