# JAXB skip invalid elements and continue processing

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an application that needs to process XML files in the following format:

```
<records>
    <record/>
    <record/>
    <record/>
    ...
</records>
```

I am using JAXB to parse these files. However I am trying to prepare my application for the inevitable occurrence for when it is unable to parse one of the records due to some invalid data (for example a character where an int should be).

The problem is that if JAXB is unable to parse an individual record, it halts processing on the *entire* file. This is not good - I need it to only skip the problematic record, report it, and move on. However I can't discover any way to do this. The only thing I've found is the `ValidationEventHandler` which lets me return `true` telling JAXB to continue processing the file in the event of an error, but the problem with that is that it doesn't actually **SKIP** the problematic record - it tries to parse it even though it's known to be invalid, which causes `NumberFormatException` and halts processing.

I found this answer [How to skip a single jaxb element validation contained in a jaxb collection in Spring Batch Job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880460/how-to-skip-a-single-jaxb-element-validation-contained-in-a-jaxb-collection-in-s) but it doesn't actually answer the question, just suggests to use `ValidationEventHandler` even though that functionality is not sufficient.

How can I skip the invalid records and continue processing? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I wouldn't use JAXB if I knew that the input data will likely contain errors and I need to gracefully recover... STAX might be better suited. But, Jaxb does have a "catch all" you can use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html

Comment: Shame.....looks like STAX gives much more finer control over the parsing. So you think JAXB just simply can't support this functionality? That does seem to be what I've run into....

Comment: JAXB is for exchanging information with other formal implementations that are known to produce valid XML. It does not do much in the way of error recovery, because XML is just not that hard to create correctly. With a proper XSD, the transmitter should be verifying their XML before sending.